# How to import gmail contacts in IONIC App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am currently working on an IONIC application and my task is to import the contacts from `gmail`, using `#cordova`. Someone please guide me how should I do this.

Answer (score 1):

This link helped me to develop the functionality of getting google contacts into ionic app,https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en_US.
Here a small issue might be faced due to XML results form google api.
That can also be resoleved when we convert XML data into JSON using javascript or anyother .